# Hibernate :Testing Daos

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, testing

My project is a legacy project with core java and hibernate.No unit tests are written over here.What can be best strategy for testing in this scenario?

P.S.  If i use mockito then I wont be able to test my queries ,so I dont want to use any Mock test framework (e.g. Mockito, EasyMock ,PowerMock) etc. I can write junits but they will be again hitting my real db.I have considered using in memory db.

Comment: It's not a unit test if you have to hit a database or other external resource. It's an integration test, regardless of whether it's your true database or a stubbed database.

Comment: thats correct, updated title accordingly

Comment: Integration test is such a big word. I call it module-tests. Especially if JPA together with Spring or CDI is used, it is quite easy to use frameworks for testing your application code unchanged together with an inmemory-Database. H2 has modes for Postgres and Mysql which simulate the syntax quite well, so that even nativesql can be used.

Answer (score 1):

It's common approach to use in-memory DBs for writing DB tests ( they considered to be integration tests though ). But there are some pros and cons you need to take into consideration:

**Pros**:

You should not think about cleaning up.

You can setup DB in whatever way you need.

It's easy to handle such kind of working environment. You don't need to install anything additional.

**Cons**:

DB that you use for testing is different.

Transactions may not work.

DB objects may not work.

Some sql constructions may not work.

So taking into consideration all cons, I would suggest using **docker** containers with DB installed inside. Each time you will have clean db, you should not care about data clean up and furthermore this will be exactly same DB as you have in prod.